# xamarin.forms getting the internet type and quality

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a way to know in Xamarin.Forms, if the internet type is 2G / 3G / 4G ?

I also need to know the internet quality (meaning BER - bit error rate so far)

Answer (score 1):

You can use James Montemagno's [Connectivity plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin) for this.
With it, you can check if you have an internet connection as a whole. Also, it exposes a property `IEnumerable<ConnectionType> ConnectionTypes { get; }` by which you should be able to determine the type of connection you have available.

I don't think it's that much advanced that you can get error rates and such, but this should be a great starting point. Maybe you can extend it yourself and open a PR!